# How to get second asset?

Tags: assets, assets-field

I have an entry with an asset field that has up to 3 assets in it. If I want to load just the second asset in my template code, what's the syntax for this? (can't find any references/examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image assets are returned in an array. Let's say you have an assets field with the handle of `images`. You can just use bracket notation to get the second item in the array using: `entry.images[1]`. So if you wanted to return the URL you could just do:

```
{{ entry.images[1].url }}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Craft 3 this should be:

```
  {% if entry.images | length > 1 %}
    {% set secondImage = entry.images.1 %}
  {% endif %}
```